# How to POST point location to Salesforce REST API?

Tags: rest, salesforce

What is the right JSON format to post a geolocation (point) to the Salesforce REST API? I am getting either deserialization or permission errors (despite wide open administrator permissions in my sandbox).

I tried:

```
{"location__c": {"latitude": 34, "longitude": 23}} # the actual return when a GET the field
```

and

```
{"location__c__latitude": 34, "location__c__longitude": 23}
```

and

```
{"latitude__c": 34, "longitude__c": 23} # this one out of desperation.
```

Obviously with all the necessary boilerplate and authentication. Posting to other custom fields works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_geolocate_overview.htm&language=en
you need to specify them in a slightly different format, like so:

```
location__latitude__s, location__longitude__s
```

So, if you have an object with a geolocation (let's say an object called "house"), you'd do

```
{"house":{"location__latitude__s":34, "location__longitude__s":23}}
```